# How to calculate Date difference in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm a novice. I have a employee table with a column specifying the joining date and I want to retrieve the list of employees who have joined in the last 3 months. I understand we can get the current date using from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()). How do I calculate the datediff? Is there a built in DATEDIFF() function like in MS SQL? please advice!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
datediff(to_date(String timestamp), to_date(String timestamp))
```

For example:

```
SELECT datediff(to_date('2019-08-03'), to_date('2019-08-01')) <= 2;
```

Comment: `to_date` is unnecessary if the column is already in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

Comment: `The DATEDIFF function returns the number of days between the two given dates`
[hadoop tutorial](http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-date-functions/#DATEDIFF_string_date1_string_date2)

Answer (score 10):

If you need the difference in seconds (i.e.: you're comparing dates with timestamps, and not whole days), you can simply convert two date or timestamp strings in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' (or specify your string date format explicitly) using unix_timestamp(), and then subtract them from each other to get the difference in seconds. (And can then divide by 60.0 to get minutes, or by 3600.0 to get hours, etc.)

Example:

```sql
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-05 10:01:30') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-05 10:00:00') AS time_diff -- This will return 90 (seconds). Unix_timestamp converts string dates into BIGINTs.
```

More on what you can do with unix_timestamp() here, including how to convert strings with different date formatting: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Answer (score 2):

yes datediff is implemented; see:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

By the way I found this by Google-searching "hive datediff", it was the first result ;)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. In the Language Manual, it specified that the datediff function calculate difference between string types. Does it work for Timestamp type as well?

Comment: I don't know, I never have used the timestamp type, I always just use string for my timestamp columns. If it doesn't work, just cast your timestamp column to string (or leave it as string in the first place).

Comment: DATEDIFF() only takes STRING/TIMESTAMP/DATEWRITABLE types, I suggest only use the format : YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1):

I would try this first

```
select * from employee where month(current_date)-3 = month(joining_date)
```

Comment: what about those who joined less than 3 month ago? What about those who joined in Jan - March?

Comment: if today is may, he wants those who joined in april, march and feb, similarly for june it would be may, april and march

Comment: try to run your query with current_date=2015-01-01 and joining_date=2014-12-01 what would be the result?

Comment: (date_trunc('MONTH',idate)- INTERVAL '1 MONTH ')::Date + (to_char(idate,'DD')::int -1); please help us